# whois: query by person's name?

Tags: domain, whois

Is it possible to know all of the domains registered by some individual or company using the free whois services on the internet?

A sort of "Reverese Whois"?

Answer (score 1):

No.  Unlike the good old days when most registrations were in the names of specific people and most people were identified by NIC Handles, now many registrations are registered in the name of role-based entities, e.g. "Technical Contact."

Comment: And what if I know the particular individual I'm looking for registers it with his name and a specific email address? Google doesn't seem to index whois sites.

Comment: Do you know any of the domains this person has registered?  If they're all with a particular registrar, their whois _might_ let you search by name.

Answer (score 0):

There is no possibility to do this for free. There are services which will allow you to pay them in order to do a search like you want, but obviously they will only provide you with a list of domains if they actually have them indexed, and given how extensive the number of registered domains is, it may be hard to get an accurate list.

Answer (score 0):

No, this isn't possible.

Some sites offer this service by mining the `whois` databases of domain registries, and then building up their own databases which they can reverse query.

However this is strictly against the terms of most domain registries, and is a breach of their database copyright.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use Reverse Whois from
http://www.whoisxmlapi.com/reverse-whois.php
Finds all of the domains registered by some individual or company, not free, but the bulk lookup is cheap enough

Answer (score 0):

Yes there are multiple ways to do this.

1) Search for the name of the person or email together with keyword 'whois' and sometimes that's enough to yield some results and let you go forward in your research

2) Through a website / API such as domainbigdata.com or domaintools.com. Domainbigdata is free, but domaintools have better data.

3) Some whois servers also allow to make this call directly from command line

4) Getting the "master record" for a given whois upon special request (this is what domainers use to harvest expired domain names).

When it comes to the "NIC handle" point, for country level you still often have a unique handle under which all your domains are and I think whois privacy is rare or at least far more rare at local .tld level e.g. .fi and records generally more straightforward to attain.